# How to use len and case insensitive?

Tags: python, case-insensitive

```
stop = False
text_count = 0
while stop is False:
    int_string = input("What is the initial string? ")
    int_string = int_string.lower()
    for a in int_string:
        for a in b:
            text_count += 1
    if text_count < 3:
        print("Error: string must have at least 3 characters.")
    elif len(int_string) != 'X' or len(int_string) != 'x' or len(int_string) != '_':
        print("Error: string must contain only X and _.")
```

This string must be at least 3 characters long, and it must consist only of the characters 'X', 'x', or '_' (underscore)
Case Insensitive also

Comment: You've asked 5 questions here, and accepted no answers. If an answer fixes your problem, you should click the checkmark by it. This marks the question as answered, so other people know that it's complete.

Answer (score 2):

You could convert it into a `set` object and compare it to the set of characters that you do allow:

```
while not stop:
    int_string = input("What is the initial string? ").lower()

    if len(int_string) < 3:
        print("Error: string must have at least 3 characters.")
    elif set(int_string) <= {'x', '_'}:
        print("Error: string must contain only X and _.")
```

`a <= b` is shorthand for `a.issubset(b)`.

Comment: This will break if the string contains x *or* _, but not both. A more rigorous, though slightly harder to read, approach would be something like `set(int_string) - {'x', '_'} != set()`.

Comment: @lvc: You could do `set(int_string).issubset({'x', '_'})` or use `<=`.

Answer (score 1):

Here is one more option:

```
while not stop:
    int_string = raw_input("What is the initial string? ").lower()   
    if len(int_string) < 3:
        print("Error: string must have at least 3 characters.")
    elif any(ch not in ('x', '_') for ch in set(int_string)):
        print("Error: string must contain only X and _.")
```